# How to use pandas apply to replace iterrows?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, lambda, apply

I am calculating the sentiment value on every row in the dataset based on news headline. I used `iterrows` to achieve this:

```
field = 'headline'
dfp = pd.DataFrame(columns=('pos', 'neg', 'neu'))

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("ProsusAI/finbert")

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("ProsusAI/finbert")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    text = row[field]
    encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')
    output = model(**encoded_input)
    probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(output[0], dim=-1)
    probs_arr = probs.cpu().detach().numpy()
    dfp = dfp.append({'pos': probs_arr[0][0],
                      'neg': probs_arr[0][1],
                      'neu': probs_arr[0][2]
                     }, ignore_index=True)
```

However, the processing time is taking too long (>30 minutes runtime and it is not done yet). I have 16.6k rows in my dataset.

This is a small section of the dataset:

```
    datetime            headline
0   2020-03-17 16:57:07 12 best noise-cancelling headphones: In-ear an...
1   2020-06-08 14:00:55 5G Stocks To Buy And Watch: Pricing of 5G Smar...
2   2020-06-19 10:00:00 10 best wireless printers that will make your ...
3   2020-08-19 00:00:00 Apple Confirms Solid New iOS 14 Security Move ...
4   2020-08-19 00:00:00 Apple Becomes First U.S. Company Worth More Th...
```

I have read that `iterrows` is not recommended in most situation unless the dataset is small and optimization is not a concern. The alternative to it, it seem, is to use `apply` since `apply` go through each pandas row and is optimized.

Some of the SO topics I read suggested to put create a function and run it in `apply`. This is what I attempted:

```
def calPred(text):
    encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')
    output = model(**encoded_input)
    probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(output[0], dim=-1)
    probs_arr = probs.cpu().detach().numpy()
    dfp = dfp.append({'pos': probs_arr[0][0],
                      'neg': probs_arr[0][1],
                      'neu': probs_arr[0][2]
                     }, ignore_index=True)

df['headline'].apply(lambda x: calPred(x))
```

It returned an error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dfp' referenced before assignment`.

Appreciate if someone can guide me on how to optimize and use `apply` correctly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when you do `dfp = dfp.append...`, `dfp` is already defined as global and you cannot reassign it (use another variable name) i.e `dfp_temp = dfp.append...`.

However I think that apply is not what you want. Most models in ML will take as input an array-like so you can pass the whole column in the model (or at least a big chunk of it) and not each row.

Something like this

```py
field = 'headline'

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("ProsusAI/finbert")

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("ProsusAI/finbert")

texts = df[field].values
encoded_input = tokenizer(texts, return_tensors='pt')
output = model(encoded_input)
probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(output, dim=-1)
probs = probs.cpu().detach().numpy()

dfp = pd.DataFrame({
    'pos': probs[:, 0],
    'neg': probs[:, 1],
    'neu': probs[:, 2]
})
```

Edit: Tokenizer does not support an array

you can try vectorizing the tokenizer like this

NOTE: np.vectorize and apply will not give you any significant boost since they still iterate over each element. However it is better to use apply and np.vectorize to the minimum possible extent.

```py
...
tokenizer_func = lambda text: tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')
encoded_input = np.vectorize(tokenizer_func)(texts)
...
```

Comment: note that [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) does not compile the code and is no faster than a for loop in python. all it changes is the function signature.

Comment: Well it's python you can't really compile the code u less you use a jit like numba, which I don't think it will work anyways. However it will be faster than using apply and run the model on each row.

Comment: sure, just making the point that np.vectorize isn't really helping here relative to the performance of df.apply or df.iterrows for that matter

Comment: It does because the models evaluate once. It doesn't matter if it is vectorize or apply. He can use apply for the tokenizer. The main point is to not use apply on each row for the model eval.

Comment: yeah that's fair. the main benefit may also just be coming from using df.apply rather than df.append, which could probably also be achieved with appending to a list and then using pd.concat.

Comment: If you use df.apply I don't think you even need a pd.concat if your apply function returns a data frame, but yeah.

Comment: Yep totally. Was just noting that your answer is benefitting from multiple optimizations that are worth highlighting, but np.vectorize isn't one of them (which is often not obvious to new users)

Comment: I totally agree but I don't think he can really do anything about it. I'll add it to the answer when I'm not on mobile.